# Update queries taking 0.1s each

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm writing a simple java program, that does a simple task : it takes in input a text files  folder, and it returns as output the 5 words with highest frequency per document.

At first, I tried to do it without any database support, but when I started having memory problems, I decided to change approach and configured the program to run with SQLite.
Everything works just fine now, but it takes a lot of time to just add the words in the database ( 67 seconds for 801 words).

Here is how I initiate the database :

```
    this.Execute(
                "CREATE TABLE words ("+
                "word VARCHAR(20)"+
                ");"
    );
    this.Execute(
        "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX wordindex ON words (word);"
    );
```

then, once the programs has counted the documents in the folder ( let's say N), I add N counter columns and N frequency columns to the table

```
        for(int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++)
        {
            db.Execute("ALTER TABLE words ADD doc"+i+" INTEGER");
            db.Execute("ALTER TABLE words ADD freq"+i+" DOUBLE");
        }
```

At last, I add words using the following funcion:

```
public void AddWord(String word, int docid)
{

    String query = "UPDATE words SET doc"+docid+"=doc"+docid+"+1 WHERE word='"+word+"'";
    int rows = this.ExecuteUpdate(query);

    if( rows <= 0)
    {
        query = "INSERT INTO words (word,doc"+docid+") VALUES ('"+word+"',1)";
        this.ExecuteUpdate(query);
    }
}
```

Am i doing something wrong, or it's normal for an update query to take this long to execute?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding a column (or columns) to your table for _every_ document. You should have another table that references your main word table and which is storing your documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap all commands inside one transaction, otherwise you get one transaction (with the associated storage synchronizatrion) per command.

Comment: transactions aren't supposed to mess up the AddWord function? I can't miss the INSERT command

Comment: transactions were the solution, now everything is running in less than 1 second :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

12 per second is slow but not unreasonable. With a database like MySQL I would expect it to be closer to 100/second with a HDD storage disk.

Comment: I just run a test with mysql, and it took 37 seconds for the same amount of words, that means 21 queries per second, that is quite far from yor expected 100

Comment: What sort of indexes do you have on those columns in that table? And what sort of disk storage do you have?

Comment: Indexes are the ones shown in the question, and the disk storage is my computer hd, nothing exceptional

Comment: I am surprised its not faster, but I usually avoid using databases if performance is important. If you can work in Java memory you are looking at millions of updates per second.

Comment: I'm not particularly focused on performances, but having to wait 50 minutes to parse 50 files seems quite too much ... and memory is not really an option, the number of files I have to parse is quite large and an "out of memory" error arises too often

Comment: Perhaps you can reduce your memory consumption or buy more memory. If you are running out of memory in Java, its highly likely your performance in SQL is also being hit significantly. i.e. SQL databases performs best when they have plenty of free memory.